# How to download pyaudio

Tags: pip, pytorch, pyaudio

I am unable to download pyaudio.

I tried `pip install pipwin`.
then `pipwin install pyaudio`.

but after hitting enter my terminal is not showing anything,
It was almost 3hrs no errors nothing was showed in terminal regarding successful download or any error nothing and also was not able to close the terminal. What's the solution to this.

Comment: If you are using `python3` then try `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

To download pyaudio:

1. Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. Search and download pyaudio.
3. Open file explorer cut pyaudio file which you have downloaded.
4. Open your python site-pakages folder in your computer.
5. Paste file.
6. In search bar type `cmd`.
7. Type `pip install pyaudio`.

Once it is installed, close `cmd` and file explorer and press winkey+r. Then type `cmd` and type `pip install pyaudio`.

Comment: Formatting the answer using markdown syntax will improve the readability.